# Does Blender have a tool similar to Smooth Boundary in Meshmixer?

Tags: modeling, mesh

Meshmixer has a feature called "smooth boundary" where parts of a mesh can be selected and then deformed such that the border of the selection is smoothed along with the unselected portions of the mesh that surround the selected area. Does Blender have a similar function?

Comment: I'm not sure what it is you mean, could you lost a link to a video or screenshot of the effect?

Comment: The following link is from a deleted answer that may have been better submitted as a comment: There is an add-on called [Smooth Boundary](https://blendermarket.com/products/smooth-boundary) on Blender Market that may do what you want if you find that Blender's built-in tools are not giving you the results you are after. (I have no affiliation with, nor have I used the add-on.)

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You can use either the smooth function (search it in the program, or use it from the toolshelf), or, for more control, use proportional editing. The latter even comes with a few falloff setups to choose from!

**Please Take Notice:** The latter is really intended more for if you're physically editing the mesh in some manner, but with a strong enough effect radius, the actual movement requirement can be minuscule.